# need advice in designing sms aplication for android

Tags: android, listview, sms

i am designing a sms application for android. i have been successful in sending and receiving the sms. The only problem i have been facing is the layout of the inbox and outbox of my app. I am putting up a image of what i want output like and what i am actually getting right now. Can anyone guide me in achieving the desired result.

The code i have used to fill the inbox is as below

```
public class Inbox extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_inbox);
    ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    List<String> msgList = getSMS();
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, msgList);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
}

public List<String> getSMS() {
    List<String> sms = new ArrayList<String>();
    Uri uriSMSURI = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
    Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(uriSMSURI, null, null, null,null);
    while (cur.moveToNext()) {
        String address = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("address"));
        String body = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body"));
        sms.add("Number: " + address + " .Message: " + body);
    }
    return sms;
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_inbox, menu);
    return true;
}
}
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: use custom adapter instead of array adapter to achieve your expected output .Go through this http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1763429

Comment: @SreeRanga will that change the output?

Comment: you can customhouse how it should look in a list view with a custom adapter for eg image + text etc..

Comment: @droidhot and how can i make those items clickable so that it can be opened in detailed view as you can in the image above.

Comment: a coustom adapter is just an adapter every thing else works like a listview itself refer lazy listview for reference

Comment: go through this.https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_mms

Comment: thank you very much for sparing your time..

Comment: @SreeRanga "https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_mms" <---what its all about..

Comment: @SreeRanga i downloaded the file from your link.. but didn't find it to be helpful as it contains lot of errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create two activities or fragments and get only the number from database in the first and in the second get the messages related to that number and learn how to create custom listviews

Suggested links:

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/

http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1763429

http://www.thepcwizard.in/2012/09/android-creating-custom-listview-for.html